# System tray notification doesn't appear after execution via c#

Tags: c#, .net, system-tray

I am trying to create a sample for showing System Tray Notifications in a simple windows forms application. Basically, it looks like this:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void showToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Show();
    }

    private void exitToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Application.Exit();
    }

    private void Form1_Move(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.WindowState == FormWindowState.Minimized)
        {
            this.Hide();
            notifyIcon1.ShowBalloonTip(1000, "Important Notice", "Something important has come up. Click to view more", ToolTipIcon.Info);
        }
    }

    private void notifyIcon1_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Show();
    }
}
```

After execution and minimizing, I can't find the icon on the right side in notification window.
Can you help me in order to visualize where I am wrong?
Thank you!

Comment: is windows hiding it? is it set to `Visible = true`?

Comment: Yep, `Visible = true` is set

Comment: Did you set the `Icon` property of your `NotifyIcon` or is it empty? :)

Comment: You are right! NotifyIcon is missing because I thought that a default one will be set. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to **set an icon** manually to your `NotifyIcon`, otherwise it will not be shown (usually we think its default icon will be enough but unfortunately it is not!!)